# How to work with Python's cffi and enum arrays

Tags: python, c, enums, python-cffi

I have a function implemented in C that translates a string to an array of a defined `enum`. The C code looks like this:

Header file (describes the `enum`):

```
/* File `asdf.h` */
enum translation {
        ONE,
        ANOTHER,
        FINISH,
};

void translate(char *origin, enum translation *destination);
```

The source file (implements the function that makes the translation):

```
/* File `asdf.c` */
#include "asdf.h"


void translate(char *origin, enum translation *destination)
{
    while (1) {
        if (*origin == 'F')
            break;
        if (*origin == 'O')
            *destination++ = ONE;
        if (*origin == 'A')
            *destination++ = ANOTHER;
        origin++;
    }
    *destination = FINISH;
}
```

Now I would like to be able to call this function from Python, using [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and being able to check the correct values of the output array (translation). How could I do that?

I have tried to compile the module first and then create the variables and call the function this way, but did not manage to make it work:

```
# File `cffienum.py`
from pathlib import Path
from cffi import FFI


ffibuilder = FFI()
ffibuilder.cdef(Path('asdf.h').read_text())
ffibuilder.set_source(
    '_asdf',  # name of the output C extension
    '#include "asdf.h"',
    sources=['asdf.c'])   # includes asdf.c as additional sources
ffibuilder.compile()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from _asdf.lib import translate

    ffi = FFI()
    ffi.cdef(Path('asdf.h').read_text())
    c = ffi.dlopen('c')
    source = ffi.new('char source[]', b'OAF')
    destination = ffi.new('enum translation destination[10]')

    translate(source, destination)
    print(source, destination)
```

This is the error I get:

```
$ pipenv run python cffienum.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cffienum.py", line 24, in <module>
    translate(source, destination)
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'enum translation *' must be a pointer to same type, not cdata 'enum translation[10]'
```

First contact with CFFI and not an experienced C programmer, so I bet I am doing many things wrong here.

### Update

Note that if instead of:

```
void translate(char *origin, enum translation *destination)
```

I use:

```
void translate(char *origin, char *destination)
```

Or:

```
void translate(char *origin, uint8_t *destination)
```

It works just fine. So there is something I must be missing when using `enum translation *`...

Comment: It would help readers if you could paste the error that you get.

Comment: @ArminRigo You are right, I updated my question with the error I am getting. Thanks for your help. ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the ffi object from the `_adsl` module:

```
from _asdf import ffi
```

instead of making a new FFI instance and redefining an unrelated type `enum translation` that happens to be identical.

Comment: Thanks! At first I tried using `ffibuilder` instance, but that did not work and I ended up with that nonsense code. Using the `ffi` object from the compiled module works perfectly. ^^